# CloudKit query for reference in array

Tags: ios, swift, cloudkit

Let's say I have two CloudKit record types:

- Company

  - name (string)
  - etc...
- Employee

  - first name (string)
  - etc...
  - company (reference to Company)

In my app if I have an array Companies, is there a way to query CloudKit for all Employees whose company is in this array with a single query? Obviously I could go through the `companies` array and query one by one, but if this array is large then that's going to be a lot slower.

The [docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/cloudkit/ckquery#) say that you can reference an array in a CKQuery predicate, but doesn't say how.

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can use the predicate

NSPredicate(“%k IN %@“, company, arrayofcompaniesReference)

- company is the key in employee record type
- arrayOfCompaniesReference is the array of reference of companies you have.